# Issues with contentEditeable and document.execCommand('bold',..)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am allowing some small inline editing on my blogpost page with the following code:

```
BlogEditor.prototype.applyBindings = function(argument){
    var makeBoldProxy = $.proxy(this.makeBold, this);
    var enableEditingProxy = $.proxy(this.enableEditing,this);
    this.boldButton.bind('click', makeBoldProxy);
    this.enableEditingButton.bind('click', enableEditingProxy);
};

BlogEditor.prototype.enableEditing = function(argument){
    $('#blogContent *').attr('contenteditable','true');
    this.isEditing = true;
    this.toggleControls();
};

BlogEditor.prototype.makeBold = function(argument){
    if(!this.isEditing){
        return;
    }
    document.execCommand ('bold', false, null);
};
```

the makeBold statemtent is called (locally i have some logs in there to check).

**Problem** The selected text is not made bold. Any ideas why this is not working?

the problem seems to be html5, the functionality works perfectly i realised, but the browser wont show the  tags in bold anymore ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What web browser are you using?

Take a look at this page, this works for chrome/firefox/safari:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Comment: i am using chrome currently but it should work on all the above :)

Comment: Take a look at this page : http://help.dottoro.com/ljcvtcaw.php
The problem is probably that you didnt set the contenteditable